# Testing REST API using Robot Framework. Can't upload a CSV File and data via POST request

Tags: python-requests, robotframework

I am very new to testing / developing. I am currently testing a `REST API`. In `Postman` I send a `POST` request by specifying parameters and uploading a `.csv` file using `form-data` in the body. My request always succeeds. However, when I try to translate this into `Robot Framework` (using the `Requests Library`), I get a `400 Error`.

I am posting my code below.

I have been trying to resolve this issue for a while now. Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated!

```
  Create Session  Alias  http://{{HOST}}{{PORT}}

  ${data}  Create Dictionary   inputFileTypeId=1  dataType=csv 

  Set to Dictionary   ${data}

  ${file_data}  Get Binary File  ${CURDIR}${/}File1.csv

  ${files}  Create Dictionary  file  ${file_data}

  Log  ${files}

  Log  ${data}

  ${resp}  RequestsLibrary.Post Request  ALias  /URI  files=${files}  data=${data}

  Log  ${resp}


  Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}  200
```

Comment: The contents of the ${data} dictionary are different from what the server is expecting. Hence the server is sending a 400 response. So I would assume that there is something wrong with the ${data} that you are setting.

Comment: @Dandekar I use the same contents on Postman and it works. When I check the log, under the post request details, it shows data=<empty> . Any thoughts on why that might be the case?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the server logs? Maybe they will tell you why it thinks the data is incorrect.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for the suggestion, really helped me figure it out! Turns out all I had to do was change the name of the file from "file" to "file.csv."

Comment: If you no longer have the problem, please consider either writing an answer that explains the solution, or delete the question.

Comment: @JKal: Glad to know that worked. I looked at your code again and realized that the 'data' dictionary contains the form-data, and the 'files' dictionary contains the actual data...

Answer (score 1):

```
Create Session  Alias  http://{{HOST}}{{PORT}}

${data}  Create Dictionary   inputFileTypeId=1  dataType=csv 

Set to Dictionary   ${data}

${file_data}  Get Binary File  ${CURDIR}${/}File1.csv

${files}  Create Dictionary  File1.csv  ${file_data}

Log  ${files}

Log  ${data}

${resp}  RequestsLibrary.Post Request  ALias  /URI  files=${files}  data=${data}

Log  ${resp}

Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}  200
```